# Surface Area of a sphere with integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

For finding the surface area of a sphere, I tried to add up all the circles that you get when you go up and down the y axis. The radius of each of those circles would be "x" where $x^2+y^2=r^2$ where r is the radius of the sphere. Therefore, the surface area of the sphere should be $2\cdot\int_{0}^{r}2\cdot\pi\sqrt{r^2-y^2}dy$. I multiplied by 2 first because $0$ to $r$ along the y is only the top hemisphere. However, solving or plugging into Desmos gives $\pi^2r^2$. What's wrong with the logic here? Shouldn't the surface area of the sphere be the sum of all the circle's circumference as I have done here

Comment: I know there's something wrong but I can't find it. How are you building the circles "when you go up and down the $y$ axis?"

Comment: The little circles aren't like sections of a cylinder -- they're like sections of a cone. Think about how you'd find the length of a semicircle using the same approach.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I'm adding up all the circles that are produced by the given x-radius as I move up and down the the y-axis. For each y value of the circle, there is a corresponding x value which I use as the radius. The x value is given by that sqrt of r^2 minus y^2.

Comment: If I understand right, you're trying to nest circles - that is not how surface area is computed. You need to use the formula $\int_a ^b 2\pi y(x) \ ds$, where $ds$ is the arc length differential.

Comment: It is hard to rigorously explain how to determine the surface of a sphere with one-variable caculus. You can try to apply **surface intergral**.

Comment: But this kind of thinking works when I calculate volume so why not surface area?

Comment: hint: try this method on a pyramid, and you will see what you have missed.

Comment: Express your integral as an infinite sum to see where the problem is with your approach.

Comment: The "circles" you're stacking aren't actually circles, but [*spherical frusta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment). Their "circumferences" are actually areas of 2D surfaces in 3D space, and this contributes an additional factor that you're not accounting for.